# Dustbin in Dash or Dock, How?

Tags: dock

How can I get a dustbin in the Dash, Dock or Tray, whatever you call it?
To be specific: Not on the desktop. I do know that already but is not what I mean.
I'm using 14.04 Gnome. Thanks in advance.